# Game Center Leaderboards - Get global ranking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

So basically I want to display a ranking percentile using Game Center leaderboards, ie get the rankings and total # of entries.

I've read that Game Center's leaderboard API only returns 100 entries maximum, and only returns relative rankings (based on those 100 entries). This feels like a big missing feature, considering even Apple's official game center widget can display rankings.

Is my only option to create a custom leaderboard? Or is there anything else I can do? Thanks!